# IMDb Ratings: Keeping only distinct records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, window-functions

I'm working on a personal project where I'm looking at IMDb movie ratings across a group of friends. I'm trying to make a master dimension table with all of the movies and their attributes. There are duplicates when multiple people rated a movie and I'd like to get the distinct list of movies. There are 4 attributes that change depending on when someone rates a movie: DateCreated, IMDb_Rating, Genre, and Votes. How can I only keep the row with the "most recent" data?

Here's an example of what is happening:

[image]

As you can see, the DateCreated is the same, but the IMDb_Rating, Genre, and Votes are different between some of the rows. My solution would be to just keep the row with the highest votes.

In pseudo-code, I think I'd use a window ranking function like RANK() and rank each group of MovieID, Title, Director, Runtime, and DateRelease by **Votes**. Then I would create a table where only the rows with the highest rank are returned.

Does this make sense? Any help with the code would be incredible!

Comment: Not at all related to the question, but you might want to look into normalizing your database a little bit more, as it looks like right now you're storing a bunch of duplicate information.  Of course, it's completely up to you, but storing it the way you are will cause your database to grow much more quickly than it otherwise would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select MovieID, Title, Director, Runtime, DateRelease,
MAX(Votes) as maxvotes
INTO #sometable
from yourtable
group by MovieID, Title, Director, Runtime, DateRelease
```

`MAX` will do what you need. You can then use `into` to insert the row with maximum votes into a new table.

One other solution would be to use a `row_number` window function.

```
select MovieID, Title, Director, Runtime, DateRelease,
IMDb_Rating, DateCreated, Genre
from
(select *, row_number() over(partition by movieid order by votes desc) as rn
 from yourtable) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But how then do I include the IMDb_Rating, DateCreated, and Genre associated with that max(Votes)?

Comment: @Walker..see the modified solution.

Comment: Works great! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Select <<column names>> 
INTO #sometable
From 
 (select *,
Row_Number() OVER(Partition by MovieID, Title, Director, Runtime, DateRelease Order by Votes Desc) as R_num
from yourtable
 ) Res
Where R_num = 1
```